# R - Create a list of network objects based on variable ID

Tags: r, networking, sna

I am new to network analysis, so I apologize in advance for any inconsistencies or mistakes in my question.

I have an edgelist where each edge represents a Twitter mention (from userID to userID) within a specific conversation (convoID).

The same edgelist contains information about which conversation any given edge belongs to, as well as the weight of that edge expressed with an integer representing the number of times any given edge occurred *within* the same conversation (for example, user1 replied to user2 3 times in conversation 144; user1 replied to user2 8 times in conversation 12, and so on).

This is what the data looks like:

```
edgelist <- data.frame(my_convo = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6),
                       from = c("user2", "user3", "user4", "user5",
                       "user2", "user1"),
                       to = c("user1", "user1", "user1", "user1",
                       "user1", "user2"),
                       num_replies = c(1,1,1,1,10,8))
```

I would like to create a network for each conversation, but my dataset currently has thousands of conversations. I have been trying to create a full network and use my_convo as a grouping factor so that each network can be analyzed independently, but since the same edge can take place in different conversations (see user2 to user1 occurring in conversations 5 an 6 above), these appear as duplicates.

I would like to avoid creating a network object for each conversation due to the large volume of the data, but I don't know how to create the network object including my_conversation as a grouping variable. Is this even a possibility?

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what you mean by "create a network for each conversation". Would you be defining 'network' as the 'overall network of all possible combinations of all individual users'? The conversation ID acts as a grouping factor yes, however I would think the network existence is agnostic of the conversation instance alone.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. The conversations can also represent an intersecting node.  [](https://imgur.com/IAgKuJw)

Comment: @CarlBoneri Yes, I'm trying to create a network for each group of user-to-user interactions grouped within the same ID. That is how conversation is operationalized.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have resolved this through the following code:

```
convo_networks <- lapply(sort(unique(edgelist_weighted$my_convo)), function(i) { 
   as.network(edgelist_weighted[which(edgelist_weighted$my_convo==i),], 
   directed=T, ignore.eval=F, names.eval="num_replies", matrix.type ="edgelist")
})
```

Essentially, I am creating a list of network objects by iterating through each conversation ID present in the original edgelist and creating one network object in each of these iterations. However, in terms of time and given the great number of conversations, this is not the most efficient method.